# Concrete5 8.3 implement Ajax other view

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, concrete5, concrete5-8.x

I have a problem recovering a variable in a view.

I followed [this tutorial](https://documentation.concrete5.org/developers/working-with-blocks/creating-a-new-block-type/implementing-ajax-block-view-templates):

Once I have the other view, I can not send a variable so that I can get it back in the view.

Controller.php

```
      public function action_like($token = false, $bID = false)
{
    if ($this->bID != $bID) {
        return false;
    }
    if (Core::make('token')->validate('like_page', $token)) {
        $page = Page::getCurrentPage();
        $u = new User();
        $this->markLike($page->getCollectionID(), $page->getCollectionTypeID(), $u->getUserID());
        if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest') {
            $b = $this->getBlockObject();

            //Normaly we set a variable for get in the view 
            // $this->set('test', 'test');

            $bv = new BlockView($b);
            $bv->render('view/view');            
        } else {
            Redirect::page($page)->send();
        }
    }
    exit;
}
```

view/view.php

```
<?php echo $test; ?>
<p> Title  <p/>
```

thanks for answers

Comment: What you mean by "the other view"?

Comment: I want set a view at $bv->render('view/view');

Answer (score 0):

> Sessions provide a way to store information across multiple
>   requests/pages.

You may use :

```
//...
$_SESSION["test"] = "test";
//...
```